# Does WordPress use the InnoDB engine for MySQL by default?

Tags: database, mysql, innodb

I just created a new WordPress site in my server. Normally, WordPress uses MyISAM as the database type. But this time, it created all InnoDB tables! Is this normal? Has WordPress switched to InnoDB in the latest versions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> WordPress actually specifies no table type in the create statements, so it uses MySQL's default table engine which is InnoDB from version 5.5 onwards.

Comment: Shall i keep it that way or change back to MyISAM?

Comment: That's up to you and depends on your use case - there's a lot of discussion that you can find via Google, but in most cases InnoDB simply is faster.

Comment: InnoDB is fine, for most cases. Some search plugins will try to add FULLTEXT indexes, and you may need to convert some tables to MyISAM to be able to add those indexes, but if you don't need FULLTEXT then it generally doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Otto: Beating the dead horse: Using since Mysql 5.6 there is FULLTEXT support in InnoDB. (ref: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/26/myisam-vs-innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-1/). Just adding up.

Answer (score 1):

It matters when it comes to backing up your Wordpress site.  I learned this the hard way.   If the DB is innodb then R1 cloud restore type backups won't save all the data because it has to be shut down first in order to back it up.  Whereas MYISAM can be backed up no problem.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Never mind, it's useful and should stay here. Only problem: Is there a source or was that learned the hard way? If there's a source, would you mind linking to it?

Comment: This is true for raw backups, but normaly you don't do raw backups of a MySQL database but create a dump instead.

Comment: [Mariabackup](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariabackup-overview/) can make "hot online" backups of InnoDB in MariaDB.