# WordPress site uses MyISAM, should I switch to InnoDB necessary?

Tags: database, mysql

I've been managing a site for a long time, so the database still uses MyISAM for database engine. So, now that I transferred the site to a new server using mysql 8.0.19 (before it was 5.7), I'm wondering if I need to switch to InnoDB.

If yes, how to backup innodb db? Any different from MyISAM using mysqldump? Can I backup when the site is live?

I'm asking because I read this ([WordPress use innodb by default?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63093/wordpress-use-innodb-by-default)): It matters when it comes to backing up your Wordpress site. I learned this the hard way. If the DB is innodb then R1 cloud restore type backups won't save all the data because it has to be shut down first in order to back it up. Whereas MYISAM can be backed up no problem.

**Update info for @gordan-bobic**

```
| wp_comments | CREATE TABLE `wp_comments` (
  `comment_ID` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_post_ID` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_author` tinytext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comment_author_email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_url` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_IP` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_content` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comment_karma` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_approved` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `comment_agent` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_type` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_parent` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_ID`),
  KEY `comment_post_ID` (`comment_post_ID`),
  KEY `comment_approved_date_gmt` (`comment_approved`,`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_date_gmt` (`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_parent` (`comment_parent`),
  KEY `comment_author_email` (`comment_author_email`(10))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16593 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Update 2

@gordan-bobic I updated the my.cnf to remove the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE` and it worked using this guide https://ixnfo.com/en/the-solution-of-error-error-1067-42000-at-line-211-invalid-default-value-for-blablabla.html

So basically, this is what I had on my installation:
`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` using this command `show variables like 'sql_mode';`

So I updated the my.cnf file with this:
`sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Then I used the command to convert the tables to InnoDB and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have switched to InnoDB at some point in the past decade, but now is as good a time as you are going to find. :-)

mysqldump will work the same way.

MyISAM could not be backed up while the database is running either. Databases generally cannot be backed up by running using a naive method like taring up the files. The data has to be static / point-in-time consistent. So if you take a snapshot and back up a snapshot, that is fine.

With InnoDB you can also use xtrabackup, which is faster to back up and much, much faster to restore than mysqldump. You can also use mysqldump --single-transaction to back up without locking the tables (mysqldump with MyISAM results in all tables being locked during the backup process).

Comment: Is this the right command to convert the tables `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;`? Also, can I run this command while the website is live? Does it matter converting one table at a time while the remaining tables of WordPress are MyISAM? Thanks,

Comment: Yes, that is the right command. You can run it while the site is live, but writes to the table will be blocked while the table is rebuilt. How long the table rebuild will take depends on the table size. Make sure you set innodb_file_per_table=1 in your config file and restart mysqld before you do it. There is no problem with converting one table at a time.

Comment: Thank you and you meant to include `innodb_file_per_table=1` in the my.cnf file, right?

Comment: Yes, in the `[mysqld]` section. Make sure you restart mysql for it to take effect before you convert the tables.

Comment: So, tried, for I'm getting errors on some tables: 
mysql> ALTER TABLE wp_comments ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'comment_date'

mysql> ALTER TABLE wp_links ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'link_updated'

mysql> ALTER TABLE wp_posts ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'post_date'

mysql> ALTER TABLE wp_users ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'user_registered'

Comment: What is the default value you have set for those fields? What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` say for the affected tables?

Comment: Please check the main question above, updated with the info, since it's too long to post it here. Thanks,

Comment: Right, so you set your default date to an invalid date. Newer versions of MySQL enforce higher levels of strictness. Either alter the table to change the default to something valid, e.g. `0001-01-01 00:00:00` or change the `sql_mode` to remove the following options: `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE`

Comment: Please, see "update 2" above. So I changed the sql_mode to remove `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE` using the my.cnf file. Should I remove the line added to the my.cnf after converting the tables. Also, the zeros for tables is the default setup for WordPress installation. Thanks,

Comment: If invalid dates are acceptable to you, you shouldn't remove the acceptance of invalid dates.

Comment: Thanks, it's not that I want to use invalid dates, that's how WordPress is designed, I just don't want to have problems with it.

Comment: It seems unlikely that WordPress defaults weren't changed to work with default MySQL settings in current versions of both.